# Specify line start while anchoring line end in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This question has probably been asked, but I can't find the right search terms. I have a line from `X: 158.4194 pt` to `X: 732 pt`. I want the line to be from `X: 170 pt` to `X: 732 pt`. Is there a way to change the left/start of the line without calculating the distance from 170 to 732 (562), anchoring the line on the right, and then manually entering `W: 562`?

[image: transform panel]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select with the white arrow (=the direct selection tool) the line endpoint which should be moved and type to the info bar the new coordinates of the selected point.